# Plotly small numbers as power

Tags: python, plotly

I am using plotly to plot data (small numbers - piko and nano) and I change a format of yaxes on "power".

`fig.update_yaxes(exponentformat = 'power')`

And I wonder if I can change the display of y-axis ticks? I would like to see 1.2 instead of 1.2x10 ^ -12 and a power at the top of the axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/yaxis/#layout-yaxis-showexponent
- code below demonstrates this

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

px.line(y=np.linspace(10**-12, 10**-9, 20)).update_yaxes(exponentformat = 'power', showexponent="last")
```

[image]